# Jquery: getting range inputs and then displaying them in a div

Tags: jquery, forms

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#slider").change(function() {
        //get value from slider
        var data = $("slider").val();

        //display data in id slider_value
        $("slider_value").text(data);
    });

});
```

What I'm trying to do is get the value of #slider

```
<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="1000" />
```

and display it in the div="slider_value". The problem seems to be that I am unable to get the value of the input range.

I'm new to Jquery so it's more than likely something I'm doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Nzgw/3/

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you using MooTools in conjunction with jQuery? Cause in your fiddle the `<inout type="range" />` element seems to refer to MooTools, while your code seems to mimick a jQuery environment?

Comment: Fixing the HTML and including the script sure seemed to help -> http://jsfiddle.net/7Nzgw/1146/

Comment: Ahhh! Well spotted. I forgot the # at the beginning of the variables. I'm glad it's something simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$("slider_value") is a null selector.

use $(".slider_value") or $("#slider_value")